# Can a VLOOKUP take an array as criteria?

Tags: excel, formula

Instead of:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Red",$AA$5:$AB$54,2,FALSE),0) + IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Green",$AA$5:$AB$54,2,FALSE),0) + IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Blue",$AA$5:$AB$54,2,FALSE),0)
```

Can I write something like this?

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Array("Red","Green","Blue"),$AA$5:$AB$54,2,FALSE),0)
```

I tried:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(AND("Red","Green","Blue"),$AA$5:$AB$54,2,FALSE),0)
```

But that returned `#VALUE` (when no `IFERROR` in place)

Or if I have a list of 20+ values, can I write them into a named range which could be used as the criteria?

Comment: Looks more like a SUMIF to me.

Comment: @ScottCraner `=SUMIF(AA5:AA54,OR("Red","Green","Blue"),AB5:AB54)` still returns 0 for me as well. Is there another way to write multiple criteria into a `SUMIF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(AA:AA,{"Red","Green","Blue"},AB:AB))
```

You can also replace the `{"Red","Green","Blue"}` with a range of cells.

[image]